# How to prove a smooth curve $c(t), t ∈ [a, b]$ is parameterized by arc length iff $a=0$ and $|c'(t)| = 1$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Here's the original problem:

> Let $c = c(t)$ be a smooth (parametrized) curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $t ∈ [a, b]$.
> Show that $c$ is parametrized by arc length if and only if $a = 0$ and $|c'(t)| =
>  1$.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to compute arc length for a given parametrization?

Comment: @GReyes yes I integrate from a to b of abs(c'(t)) with respect to t, if im not mistaken? But I don't get why 'a' must equal 0. 
also isn't arclenght normally calculated by converting t to s or something like that?

Comment: The statement of the question is a bit unclear. By choosing $a=0$ you are measuring your arc length from the point $c(a)$ and you have $t=s$ then.

Comment: @GReyes wait why? how can a=0 if for example I chose some a >0? then it somehow is not computable?

Comment: It has nothing to do with being computable. The point is that you want your parameter to be precisely the arc length measured from $c(a)$.

Comment: Suppose your parameter is the arc length measured from $c(a)$. Then $|c'(t)|=|c'(s)|=1$ and $a$ is the arc length of the arc starting at $c(a)$ and ending at $c(a)$, i.e. zero. Now you have to prove the opposite implication.

Comment: @GReyes ok so I have to assume first t = s? since for it to start at 0 I have to first do s(t) = integral(abs(c'(t)), 0, a)

Comment: Now you have to assume that you have a parametrization with $a=0$ and $|c'(t)=1$ and prove that $t=s$ where $s$ is the arc length. For that you can just compute $s$ starting from $c(a)$ using the formula and convince yourself that $s=t$.

Comment: @GReyes thank you! I think I got it now.